# How to withdraw dollars to Dwolla from Mt Gox

Tags: mtgox

I have been trying to withdraw $7000 US dollars from Mt Gox to Dwolla for over a week.  I am currently level 1 verified at Mt Gox, so my strategy has been to withdraw $1000 every 24 hours for 7 days until I am able to withdraw $7000.  The total of my withdraws from Mt Gox has been $2000 over the past 2 months.

I was able to withdraw $1000 twice last week using two separate $1000 transactions 24 hours apart.  But after these two initial $1000 withdraws occurred, subsequent my withdraws have not been successful.  During these unsuccessful withdraw attempts, the Mt Gox web interface says the transactions are being processed with a pleasant green-colored background to the message, and my USD balance decrements by $1000 each time I initiate the $1000 withdraw request.

This is the Mt Gox message I receive for **unsuccessful** withdraw attemps:
[image]

However, several minutes after submitting the request, my balance returns to the previous amount from before the request by going back to the original balance.  No transaction ever occurs, and there is no message or notification the request has been canceled.

I submitted a ticket to Mt Gox for technical support, but their answers are not satisfactory.  Mt Gox tech support reps told me the system canceled my withdraw requests and told me "I should try it again."  But when I try again I have the same result - transfer does not go through.  Mt Gox tech support has not been clear about what I should do to resolve this.

I now have this message on my account, even though my balance of USD is approximatly $5000 USD:
[image]

What can I do to successfully transfer USD from Mt Gox to Dwolla in my current situation?  I have no reason to believe my sitaution is different from anyone else who is Level 1 verified at Mt Gox, so perhaps Mt Gox and Dwolla are having difficulties.  If transferring USD from Mt Gox to Dwolla is not possible in my situation, can I somehow move USD from Mt Gox to a bank account using another method?  I prefer to avoid wire transfers as they are expensive and tedious.

Comment: If you need the money sooner, you could try another exchange. Otherwise, I think your question is best answered by Mt.Gox itself, unfortunately. Vote with your money!

Comment: Tisk Tisk Mt.Gox, I've had frustrations becoming level 1 verified.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no way to know if a person has a pending Dwolla transfer for funds exiting Mt Gox.  The most confusing part about this is the pending status remains pending in Mt Gox for at least a day after Dwolla shows the transaction as having completed.

So I recommend waiting an extra day after Dwolla says the funds have transferred.  Otherwise the transfer will be canceled with no notification from Mt Gox or anyone else, and no reason is given for the transfer cancellation.  In fact, the only indication that the transfer is canceled when this happens is that the balance returns to the pre-transfer balance, and the funds never show up in Dwolla.

To Mt Gox's credit, Mt Gox did respond to my support requests.  However, getting a satisfactory response took almost two weeks of asking combined with plenty of trial and error with the Mt Gox withdraw system.